# PHP email - radio button causing problems with email

Tags: php, forms, email

I made 3 forms on a page, which are all processed by email-submit.php. 2 of the forms work as expected, but the form that uses radio buttons seems to break the styles on the email, and causes my email program to think the message is spam. There must be a mistake somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

The variable that causes problems is besttime.

I would really appreciate any help!

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $headers = 'From: "Contact Form" <no-reply@email.com>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $bestTime = $_POST['besttime'];
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . '</td></tr>';
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Title:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['title']) . "</td></tr>";       
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Company:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['company']) . "</td></tr>";           
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";   
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Best time:</strong> </td><td>"  . strip_tags($_POST['besttime']) . "</td></tr>";               
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['comments']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";
        $from = 'no-reply@email.com'; 
        $to = 'email@email.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Form';

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=email-success.php\">";
    } else {
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=email-error.php\">";
    }
}
    }
?>
```

The form:

```
            <div class="email-me-form">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="email-submit.php">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>                             

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required autocomplete="on" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="width: 283px;" for="callTime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Best Time to Call? (EST) <input style="float: right; margin: 0;" class="submit-button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Call Me"></label>

                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <div style="position: relative; top: -10px;" class="col-sm-10">
                    <div style="float: left;"><input class="radio" type="radio" name="besttime" value="AM" checked>AM</div>
                    <div style="float: left;"><input class="radio" type="radio" name="besttime" value="PM" >PM</div>

                    </div>
                </div>                                     

            </form>     
          </div>
```

Comment: its not that the use of radio buttons gets your email marked as spam.  that's a correlation not a cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dagon! The 2 other forms don't get marked as spam though. If you fill out the other forms that don't use radio buttons it's fine. That's why I think the radio button input is the problem. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I think it was just my email client being dumb. Tested it on another machine and it was fine. Thanks Dagon.